# Common Data Type in Oracle for reusability

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data type with fixed column data type and size. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
........,
CREATE_USER char(36)
)

CREATE TABLE TEST2
(
........,
CREATE_USER char(36)
)

CREATE TABLE TEST3
(
........,
CREATE_USER char(36)
)
```

If you see above I have `CREATE_USER char(36)` in almost all tables. I want to make it replaceable. So that in future I can change the type/size. For example, I call it `CREATE_USER myDataType`, so that in future I need to replace it only one place. Is it possible in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following example; that's how I understood the question.

Type first:

```
SQL> create or replace type my_type as object (name varchar2(10));
  2  /

Type created.
```

Table whose column's datatype is `my_type`

```
SQL> create table test (name my_type);

Table created.
```

Let's insert some rows:

```
SQL> insert into test values (my_type('Littlefoot'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (my_type('Littlefoot is Big'));
insert into test values (my_type('Littlefoot is Big'))
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type
```

OK, the 2nd one doesn't fit. Let's make it larger (the type, I mean):

```
SQL> alter type my_type modify attribute (name varchar2(20)) cascade;

Type altered.
```

How about now?

```
SQL> insert into test values (my_type('Littlefoot is Big'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

NAME(NAME)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MY_TYPE('Littlefoot')
MY_TYPE('Littlefoot is Big')

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

Comment: When I run `create or replace type MySchema.USER_ID_TYPE as object (name char(36))`  nothing happened. In Toad I don't see anything in Script Output window. Also, when I do `CREATE table test (testguid MySchema.USER_ID_TYPE )` it says invalid type. Am I missing anything?

Comment: TOAD doesn't say anything in Script Output window; it displays a message at the bottom of the screen (e.g. `TYPE SCOTT.USER_ID_TYPE compiled with 0 errors and 0 warnings`). The same goes for CREATE TABLE. I tested it on 11g; should work on any higher version as well.

Comment: TOAD doesn't show anything but I ran the same in SQL developer it says `insufficient privileges`. So, problem was permission issue. Thanks

Comment: Aha. You probably don't / didn't have the CREATE TYPE privilege granted.